# Why does my for loop not get argv properly?

Tags: c++

So Im new to coding, and I was wondering why my for loop is not going through argv correctly. When I run it, it doesnt run at all. Here is the bit of code that matters:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
bool isCapital[500];
bool capital;
bool isSpace[500];
bool space;
bool palindrome;
cout<<"Test";
for(int j=1; argv[j][0]!='-'; j++){
    cout<<argv[j][0];
    if('-'==argv[j][0]){
        cout<<j;
        for(int i=0; argv[j][i]!='\0'; i++){
            if((argv[j][i])==('c'|'C')){
                isCapital[j]=true;
                break;
                cout<<isCapital[j];
            }
        }
        for(int i=0; argv[j][i]!='\0'; i++){
            if((argv[j][i]==('s'|'S'))){
                isSpace[j]=true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through in a debugger to see exactly what the program does and find where it diverges from what you expect. I'd also suggest compiling with warnings.

Comment: How do you run it? What dp you pass as programs arguments? What is the input? What is the expected output?

Comment: `for(int j=1; argv[j][0]!='-'; j++){` you'll access `argv` out of range since you don't limit your loop to `argc`.

Comment: `(argv[j][i]==('s'|'S'))` doesn't do what you think it does. You want `(argv[j][i] == 's' || argv[j][i] == 'S')`.

Comment: `break; cout<<isCapital[j];` The 2nd statement won't ever be executed.

Comment: Your arrays are uninitialized so setting `isCapital[j]=true;` or `isSpace[j]=true;` means nothing since those values are indistinguishable from the random garbage in the arrays.

Comment: Whats that program supposed to do? Hint: there are functions in the standard library that check if a character is a space (`std::isspace()`) or a uppercase character (`std::isupper()`) in `<cctype>`.

Comment: If you describe what your input parameters are supposed to be and their meaning we might be better able to understand what your code is trying to achieve.

Comment: Looks like your loop condition is inverted.

Comment: Also, this approach to parsing args may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44233367/how-to-declare-a-pointer-to-pointer-to-constant-in-c/44233463#44233463 also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272550/c-command-line-parameters/51534733#51534733

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of bugs in your code but I think the code below is major one:

```
for(int j=1; argv[j][0]!='-'; j++){
    cout<<argv[j][0];
    if('-'==argv[j][0]){
```

so let us look at it in more details.

```
for(int j=1; argv[j][0]!='-'; j++){
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This part says: only execute the body of the for-loop if `argv[j][0]` **is not** a `-`

This line:

```
    if('-'==argv[j][0]){
```

says: only execute the body of the if-statement if `argv[j][0]` **is** a `-`

These two are contradictions so **execution never enters the body of the if-statement**

Maybe you want this line

```
for(int j=1; argv[j][0]!='-'; j++){
```

to be

```
for(int j=1; j < argc; j++){
```

**BTW:**

As written in a comment by @swordfish

1) Notice that

```
if((argv[j][i])==('c'|'C'))
```

is probably not what you want. You probably want:

```
if(argv[j][i] == 'c' || argv[j][i] == 'C')
```

2) Notice that your loop condition should consider `argc`

3) That `isCapital` and `isSpace` should be initialized to "all false"

Comment: Alright, all I had to do is change the != in the for loop to <= and that fixed it thank you! But just for clarification, even though it works, why is the if statement a bad idea?

Comment: @ShawnKeene -  Other programming languages interpret your construct `if (argv[j][i] == ('c' | 'C'))`  as "test if `argv[j][i]` is equal to one of `'c'` or `'C'`", but C++ does not.      The `if` statement is a bad idea because its meaning is completely different in C++ from what you apparently expect.    Look up "bitwise operations" for the specifics of what that test actually does.

Comment: In ascii `x == ('C'|'c')` turns out to be equivalent to `x == 'c'`), due to the way the encoding works (lower case letters are identical to upper case with one extra bit set), so it may superficially appear to work...